# What is difference between Demon and API?

Tags: javascript, linux, windows, api

Demon is program need to using solution.

I think also api same.

I can't define difference between demon and api?

How do you divide that?

Comment: demon is for running javascripts in node in the background on linux machines and api is a set of functions and procedures that allow the creation of applications which access the features or data of an operating system, application, or other service.

Origin

Answer (score 0):

Demon is a process that provides some useful service to the client-processes.

API is a contract between processes or even just pieces of code, so they can talk to each other. Sometimes it's the language between a demon and the client-processes.

Answer (score 0):

Daemon is a server process running in the background providing some service like spooling print files to a printer or logging diagnostic messages. Client processes communicate with a daemon process using an interprocess communication mechanism.

An API is the interface to a library which is linked to the object code of your program. Thus, it works as a part of your process. Thus in this case, only one process is doing all the work, whereas in the case of a daemon, two processes together do the work.